# How center text in my box "central"?

Tags: html, css

The DIV "central" is centerd, ok!, fine!
But: why conntent no?
Please help.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"><head><title>Center Content</title><link rel="icon" href="http://127.0.0.1/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://127.0.0.1/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<style type="text/css">
html,body{background:#aa0000;color:#fae803;}
#todo{
text-align:center;
}
.central{
text-align:center;
background:#4d9999;
border:1px solid #000;
width:90%;
margin:auto;
}
.logo{
float:left;
width:400px;
color:#000;
}
</style>
</head><body><div class="logo">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRST</div>
<div id="todo">
<div class="central">
HERE INFO CENTERED
</div></div>
</body></html>
```

yes, i need "logo" to left, in mode "float".
Really, all is "perfect", but the text "HERE INFO CENTERED" is creazy...

Why ?
How I can center this ?

Comment: Off topic: That's not what quotation marks are for.

Answer (score 3):

Your text is centered in the space remaining after the float is taken into consideration. See [this enhanced demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8tL2qrLs/).

```
.logo {
    ...
    background: #ddd;
}
```

One possible solution would be to put a negative margin on the logo that matches its width, thereby cancelling its size:

```
.logo {
    ...
    width:400px;
    margin-right: -400px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8tL2qrLs/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

As isherwood answered, this is because of the previous floating element.

I found two easy work-arounds for this:

One is modifying your html markup by adding a linebreak after the logo

```
<body>
  <div class="logo">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRST</div>
  <br>
  <div id="todo">
    <div class="central">
      HERE INFO CENTERED
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Other way is setting `display:inline-block;` to your `.central` div.

```
.central{
  text-align:center;
  background:#4d9999;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Another way would be, as your `.logo` has a static width, add a negative margin equal to it's width.

```
.logo{
  width:400px;
  float:left;
  color:#000;
  margin-right:-400px;
}
```